# count the number of consecutive integer elements in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, algorithm

Given I have an array such as follows:

```
arr = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4]
```

I would like to count the number of consecutive number sequences. Eg in the above array the consecutive number sequences (or array-slices) are:

```
[13,14]
[6,7,8]
[6,7]
```

And hence we have 3 such slices. What is an efficient Algorithm to count this? I know how I can do it O(N^2) but I'm looking for something which is better than that.

Comment: I don't think [6,7,8] is a pair. Are you looking for all continuous sequences?

Comment: Sorry - yes continuous sequences. Editing ques.

Comment: Why not [7,8] a valid pair?

Comment: @Skyler because [6,7,8] form the consecutive sequence there.

Comment: ...but [6,7] is valid, despite being a subsequence of [6,7,8] too? I don't see the difference.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh Do you just want the complete consecutive sequence, so that if there's [6,7,8] then [7,8] wouldn't be count? If so, why [6,7] was counted?

Comment: @RichSmith there's another [6,7] in the array.

Comment: ^ +1 there is another `[6,7]` close to the end of the sample array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4]
result = []
stage = []
for i in arr:
    if len(stage) > 0 and i != stage[-1]+1:
        if len(stage) > 1:
            result.append(stage)
        stage = []
    stage.append(i)
print result
```

---

Output:

```
    [[13, 14], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7]]
```

The time complexity of this code is **O(n)**. (There's only one `for` loop. And it's not hard to see that each iteration in the loop is O(1).)

Comment: I think you've just answered in Python to a Ruby question :)

Comment: @JonClements that doesn't matter - I just need to understand how this can be done in O(N) I can translate to Ruby myself. This looks good :)

Comment: @JasdeepSingh There's only one `for` loop. And it's not hard to see that each iteration in the loop is O(1).

Comment: @JonClements Sorry but I didn't notice that. Thanks :-P

Comment: Add another         
    if len(stage) > 1:
        result.append(stage)
before the print statement can make the algorithm more complete.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4]
p arr.each_cons(2).chunk{|a,b| a.succ == b || nil}.count #=> 3
```

`nil`has a special meaning to the `chunk`-method: it causes items to be dropped.

Comment: Quite cool (+1). And as a bonus it does not unnecessarily calculate the actual sequences.

Comment: Yes, but not in the immediate form `[6, 7, 8]`. It is `[[6, 7], [7, 8]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below using [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
a = [8, 13, 14, 10, 6, 7, 8, 14, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4]
prev = a[0]
hash = Hash[a.slice_before do |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
end.map{|e| [e,e.size] if e.size > 1}]
hash # => {[13, 14]=>2, [6, 7, 8]=>3, [6, 7]=>2}
hash.size # => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in O(N) time. If you just want the count,

1. Iterate through the array. Initialize counter to 0.
2. If next element is one more or one less than current element, increment the counter.
3. Continue iterating till the next element is not one more or one less than current element.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you reach the end.

**If you want sections of continuously increasing consecutive elements (not clear from your question)**

1. Iterate through the array. Initialize counter to 0.
2. If next element is one more than current element, increment the counter.
3. Continue iterating till the next element is not one more than current element.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you reach the end.

Comment: on #2, it won't work for `next element being one less than current element` check. I think you meant `if the current element is 1 less than next element or next element 1 more than current element`

Comment: @JasdeepSingh Don't you consider [1,2,1] as a consecutive sequence?

Comment: As per my understanding of consecutive numbers out of `[1,2,1]`, only `[1,2]` are consecutive.